# Loading data into my Mongo Database but unexpected 'O'

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb

I have a query, I'm trying to load data JSON into my mongodb but getting no luck with the unexpected 'O' (ObjectId). The below was taken from Git Bash.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e9f36d8246c0a6d0881d52c"),
        "name" : "Miley",
        "type" : "Dog",
        "image" : "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558233043-45af001ed5b7?ixlib=rb- 
          1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
        "description" : "Fun, Clever, Energetic and looking for her forever home ",
        "location" : "Dublin, Ireland",
        "site" : "  https://www.facebook.com/DroghedaAnimalRescue/",
        "author" : {
                "id" : ObjectId("5e9ee03ea12b1c7f80a7af8c"),
                "username" : "Johnny"
        },
        "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: `but getting no luck` can you be more specific please

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, need to add "$ " around ObjectID

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$ObjectId": "5ea0d96ebbfbef0004f8d88e"
    },
    "name": "Miley",
    "type": "Dog",
    "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558233043-45af001ed5b7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
    "description": "Fun, Clever, Energetic and looking for her forever home ",
    "location": "Dublin, Ireland",
    "site": "https://www.facebook.com/DroghedaAnimalRescue/",
    "author": {
        "id": {
            "$ObjectId": "5ea0bea88b2459000492dab7"
        },
        "username": "Animal Rescue"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```